# Select option does not display in dropdown in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, dropdown

I am trying to do if user selected the `options` in dropdown , I doest not want to the show in `options` in dropdown again.

How can I handle it? What mistake i am doing? please guide me.

```js
const FormData = memo(props => {
  const { index, adHocForms, eCRFForms, setAdHocForms } = props;
  const form = adHocForms[index];
  const { id } = form || {};

  const optionSelected = (property, value) => {
    //my code logic
    const newFormId = value.id ? value.id : null;
    const filteredData = eCRFForms.filter(options => options.id !== newFormId);

    if (index) {
      console.log(index);
    } else {
      const updateForms = [...adHocForms, value];
      setAdHocForms(updateForms);
    }
  };

  return (
 
          <div className="column">
            <Dropdown
              __key="id"
              __value="title"
              className="drop-down"
              clearable={false}
              label="Select a form"
              onChange={optionSelected}
              options={eCRFForms}
              property="adHocForms"
              value={id}
            />
          </div>
       
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Output :
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T6Tl.png) eCRFForms data

[Dropdown UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugr6t.png) Component Page

Hope this help you !

Comment: Can you help me ? [@abhay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2661032/abhay) [@Shyam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8884388/shyam)

Comment: Where r u using your `filteredData` variable?

Comment: I just try to create a logic .. but it is not working `filteredData` is not use anywhere [@Neel dsouza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8170092/neel-dsouza)

Comment: Can you get my point?  (https://stackoverflow.com/users/8170092/neel-dsouza)

Comment: You are storing your filtered data in `filteredData` so u need to use that and store it in `updateForms` to update